Compute the probability you reach $5$ tokens before running out.
Suppose you have $3$ tokens for a betting game and your goal is to bring your fortune up to $5$ tokens before running out of tokens. You devised a bold betting strategy where every turn, you will bet as many tokens as possible against the house but not any more than necessary to bring you to $5$ tokens. You always have a probability of $1/4$ to win the bet. Compute the probability you reach $5$ tokens before running out.
Answer
I have tried to solve it using Markov chain and absorption probability at $5$. If we consider absorptions $a_0 = 0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5=1$ then
$$a_1 = (3/4)a_0+(1/4)a_2,\;a_2 = (3/4)a_0+(1/4)a_4,$$
$$a_3 = (3/4)a_1+(1/4)a_5,\; a_4 = (3/4)a_3+(1/4)a_5.$$
Solving we get, $a_3 = 67/247$. Is this solution correct?
Can you also show me solutions in different ways? Can we use Martingle?

This is the best strategy if your objective is maximising the probability of reaching $5$ and your method of calculating is good.  But your notation is ambiguous: you use $3/4a_0$ to mean $\dfrac{3}{4}a_0=\dfrac{3a_0}{4}$ but it might be read as $\dfrac{3}{4a_0}$.

Using a Markov chain indeeds seems like the way to go.
I was able to confirm your results using the following Python code:
from random import randint


def simulate(n_tokens=3):
    while 0 < n_tokens < 5:
        n_bet = min(5 - n_tokens, n_tokens)
        if randint(0, 3) == 0:
            n_tokens += n_bet
        else:
            n_tokens -= n_bet
    return n_tokens


n_iterations = 10000
n_success = sum(simulate() > 0 for _ in range(n_iterations))
p_success = n_success / n_iterations
print(p_success)

This results in values around $0.27$, corresponding to the solution $\frac{67}{247}$.

I verified that your answer is correct, using the method you described.
It is not a martingale, because on average you lose money. (it is a sub-martingale)
Unfortunately I do not know other ways to tackle the problem.

If you want to solve this, you can look for a harmonic function. If I read your post correctly, the transitions between the states are as follows in a transition matrix, where $p$ is the success probability and $q:=1-p$.
$$P:=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
q&0&p&0&0&0\\
q&0&0&0&p&0\\
0&q&0&0&0&p\\
0&0&0&q&0&p\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
If we assume homogeneity, there exists a Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ with this transition matrix.
We use the Dirichlet Principle for Markov Chains. If we find a function $h:\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $h(0)=0$, $h(5)=1$ and $Ph=h$, then h is uniquely determined, and
$$h(i)=\mathbb P(\exists k:X_k=5\,|\,X_0=i),\,\text{for all i}.$$
To calculate this, we can simply express $h$ restricted to $\{1,2,3,4\}$ via
$$h=\left(Id-\begin{pmatrix}0&p&0&0\\0&0&0&p\\q&0&0&0\\0&0&q&0\end{pmatrix}\right)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\p\\p\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{p}{1-(pq)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
p^2(1+q)\\p\,(1+q)\\1+p^2q\\1+q
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If you plug in p=1/4, you'll get your initial result, i.e. $h(3)=67/247$.
I am sure there is a general solution to this (i.e. reaching n, instead of 5), but I do not know it. Also, there might be a useful martingale, but i don't see it. It is true, that $(h(X_n))_n$ is a martingale, but that is not useful here.

Where does the vector (0,0,p,p) come from? Also, do you have  a reference for the Dirchlet principle for Markov chains? Surprisingly, I'm not finding anything which gives a result like the one in your answer.

The vector (0,0,p,p) is the last column of the transition matrix without the entries for the boundary. Look in Bremaud's book on Markov Chains for example. I just wrote the result in matrix form. You may find results like this in the literature under Phasetype-distribution, where there is only a single absorbing state, but it is easy to generalise to more via Doob-transform.
